# Call a function within a trigger in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I've searched through the Internet for some resource providing me with an example of how to call a function I've created from within a trigger in PL/SQL.

I've made a function called `get_balance` that looks like this:

```
create or replace function get_balance(p_custno in number)
return number
as
v_balance account.balance%type;
begin
select balance 
into v_balance
from account
where custno = p_custno;
return v_balance;
end;
/
```

Now I want to call this function from within a trigger to check the balance before a withdrawal. I tried to do it as follows but I think it's totally wrong:

```
create or replace trigger bifer_withdrawal
before insert on withdrawal
for each row
begin
if get_balance(p_custno) <= amount then
raise_application_error(-20001, 'Not enough money in account!');
end if;
end;
/
```

Could someone please provide a newbie with an example of how to call a function from within a trigger?

Comment: you are doing correct only .... any error you got while compile this?

Comment: It compiles but I get a warning.

Comment: And the reason you won't tell us what the warning is?

Comment: Sorry Ollie, I'm new to SQL-developer and don't know where to look for the warning. I would be thankful if you could tell me where to look for it. In the script output view it only says that the trigger is compiled with warnings.

Comment: I think in SQL Developer you can use View -> Log from the main menu though I don't have SQL Developer installed on the PC I'm using today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the value for `p_custno` I have used the default `NEW` alias but see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c18trigs.htm#789) for trigger information, also René Nyffenegger's has a [good explanation](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/trigger/new_old.html) of the `NEW` and `OLD` usage:

```
create or replace 
trigger bifer_withdrawal 
before insert on withdrawal 
for each row 
begin
   if get_balance(:NEW.custno) <= amount 
   then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Not enough money in account!');
   end if;
end; 
/
```

You will need to specify what `AMOUNT` is too. If it is a variable then declare it between the `FOR EACH ROW` and `BEGIN` statements:

e.g.:

```
create or replace 
trigger bifer_withdrawal 
before insert on withdrawal 
for each row 
declare
   c_amount CONSTANT account.balance%TYPE := 5000; -- Whatever limit you need
begin
   if get_balance(:NEW.custno) <= c_amount 
   then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Not enough money in account!');
   end if;
end; 
/
```

You should ask yourself, do you need to call the function?
You could easily wrap the cursor into the trigger and save yourself the function call.
Your answer will depend upon issues around whether you want to reuse the function elsewhere etc.
I'm not advocating one way over the other but it is something to consider.

Hope it helps...

EDIT: After the two comments below, if `AMOUNT` is a column in the table `WITHDRAWAL` then:

```
create or replace 
trigger bifer_withdrawal 
before insert on withdrawal 
for each row 
begin
   if get_balance(:NEW.custno) <= :NEW.amount
   then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Not enough money in account!');
   end if;
end; 
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I should have explained my problem more precisely, `amount`is a column in the table withdrawal.